# Re-ordering a symmetric tibble

Tags: r, function, dplyr, tidyverse, tibble

Imagine we have a `tibble` like shown below. In theory, the first column acts simply a `rownames` that must have one-on-one correspondence with the columns' names.

For example, excluding the first column (`row_name`), the third column from the left is named `G`, but the the corresponding row is `E`.

I was wondering how we could re-order the rows (e.g., bring up row titled `G` two rows up) so the rows and columns match?

```
out <- tibble(row_name=factor(c("A","B","E","F","G")),`A`=as.character(1:5),`B`=as.character(c(2,NA,0:2)),
`G`=as.character(4:8),`E`=as.character(4:8),`F`=as.character(4:8))


#  row_name A     B     G     E     F    
#  <fct>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A        1     2     4     4     4    
#2 B        2     NA    5     5     5    
#3 E        3     0     6     6     6    
#4 F        4     1     7     7     7    
#5 G        5     2     8     8     8


# EXPECTED OUTPUT:

#  row_name A     B     G     E     F    
#  <fct>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 A        1     2     4     4     4    
#2 B        2     NA    5     5     5
#5 G        5     2     8     8     8
#3 E        3     0     6     6     6    
#4 F        4     1     7     7     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to reorder the rows, use `match` within `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
out %>%
   slice(match(names(.)[-1], row_name))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  row_name A     B     G     E     F    
  <fct>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A        1     2     4     4     4    
2 B        2     <NA>  5     5     5    
3 G        5     2     8     8     8    
4 E        3     0     6     6     6    
5 F        4     1     7     7     7
```

---

Or within `arrange`

```
out %>% 
    arrange(factor(row_name, levels = names(.)[-1]))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  row_name A     B     G     E     F    
  <fct>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 A        1     2     4     4     4    
2 B        2     <NA>  5     5     5    
3 G        5     2     8     8     8    
4 E        3     0     6     6     6    
5 F        4     1     7     7     7
```

Comment: then replace ends_with with `1` or `just use row_name.x

Comment: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68913797/7223434) is my question based on your request.